# Convert SQL single row multiple column output to two column(key, value) and multiple row output

Tags: sql, postgresql, unpivot

SQL output: Single row and multiple columns

Example: User table
SQL: select * from jiuser limit 1
[image: Output]

Now I need to transform the output in a key-value format where I will get 2 columns and multiple rows.

[image]

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: This is a random sample, you can use any table like employee, student etc. My actual data and query is different.

Comment: SQL cannot transpose columns to rows.  It is also conceptually wrong in that each new key/value row would be disassociated from the original unique row id (which could be several fields combined together).  At a minimum, you would need to repeat the unique row ID for each new row so that you end up with `ID | KEY | VALUE`.  I think the simplest way to achieve this is to write a short script (Python, Lua, etc.).

Comment: I need to use the query directly, hence can't use anything in between.

Comment: Do you see anyway by which we can use the result set metadata in to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lateral join:

```
select v.*
from t cross join lateral
     (values ('username', username),
             ('tenantid', tenantid::text),
             ('fullname', fullname)
     ) v(key, value);
```

Comment: I can not use any hard coding, as this is just an sample, and i have around 200+ columns in my actual query.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you consider the options in this article:
https://www.sqlshack.com/multiple-options-to-transposing-rows-into-columns/

You may also consider developing table variable and update it using cursor

```
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE (k varchar(200), v varchar(max))

INSERT INTO @tempTable
    SELECT C.name, '' FROM sys.objects O
    INNER JOIN sys.columns C ON O.object_id = C.object_id
    WHERE O.name = 'STOKLAR' AND O.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'

-- CURSOR , CAST AS VARCHAR AND UPDATE CODE HERE 

SELECT * FROM @tempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a dynamic unpivot you can use Postgres' JSON functions for that:

```
select c.column_name, c.value
from jiuser j
  cross join lateral jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(j)) as t(column_name, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a series of `UNION ALL` operands to achieve the result you are seeking.  However, please note that the Value column will all have to be the same datatype for the `UNION ALL`s to work.  Something like:

```
DECLARE @ID int = 1;

SELECT 'id' as FIELD_LABEL,
       CONVERT(varchar(500), id) AS FIELD_VALUE
  FROM jiuser
 WHERE id = @ID

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Username' as FIELD_LABEL,
       CONVERT(varchar(500), username) AS FIELD_VALUE
  FROM jiuser
 WHERE id = @ID

UNION ALL

SELECT 'TeneantID' as FIELD_LABEL,
       CONVERT(varchar(500), tenantid) AS FIELD_VALUE
  FROM jiuser
 WHERE id = @ID
```

And on and on and on . . .